# how to insert multi line string html using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have following structure and i want to append it to a `<div>` 
but it's showing a compile time error.

```
$('#row1').html("<div class="4u 12u(mobile)">
            <section>
                    <a href="#" class="image featured"><img src="images/kokan.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                    <header >
                        <h3>result[i]</h3>
                        <p></p>
                    </header>
                </section>
            </div>");
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't support multiline strings, nor can you use double quotes inside a doublequoted string, without terminating the string.

Comment: write all in one line or use concatination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#row1').html('<div class="4u 12u(mobile)">'
            +'<section>'
                    +'<a href="#" class="image featured"><img src="images/kokan.jpg" alt="" /></a>'
                    +'<header >'
                        +'<h3>'+result[i]+'</h3>'
                        +'<p></p>'
                    +'</header>'
                +'</section>'
            +'</div>');
```

You need to build a proper string, by concatenating parts. `"<div class="4u` this part was also breaking, you should use combinations of `" '' "`.

Comment: I think its should be  +'<h3>'+result[i]+'</h3>' :)